# Highlight user-installed fonts in a different color (or folder them)

Tags: fonts

Let's say I'm in Photoshop and I'm looking for a specific font I installed (I have a lot of them). I have at least 30 windows fonts I can't delete and it'd be great if the button color for user-installed fonts could be highlighted (lets say lt. blue). It sure would make it easier to find fonts. Color coding fonts is what I'm looking for. Is there a way to put them into folders? The windows fonts that I'm not able to get rid of are a HUGE pain.

TL;DR:
Is there a way to folder or color code fonts so they can be found more easily?

Thanks!

[this doesn't have to be automatic - I guess I have enough time to seperate 100+ fonts]

Comment: Short answer : Not possible...Sorry bro.

Comment: Ouch. That's kinda terrible.

Comment: If I had a few hundred/thousand I'd probably hire someone to code an windows extension for this.

Comment: Are you looking for the highlighting to occur in PS or within Windows?

Comment: Any would be great. But i'd prefer it to occur in programs like PS, Word etc.